# Can someone explain the chain rule used in this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, differential, chain-rule

I thought I fully comprehended what the chain rule is when I was dealing with only single variable calculus. Now I moved onto partial derivative and came across this exercise problem. The chain rule used in this problem is just confusing as hell for me. Read multiple times still can't get the point. I'm learning math all by myself as a hobby and really need help here.

So the problem goes like this.

If $z=f(x,y)$ has continuous second-order partial derivatives and $x=r^2+s^2$ and $y=2rs$, find (a) $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{r}}$ and (b) $\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{r^2}}$

(a) The chain rule gives

$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}+\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}(2r)+\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}(2s)$

(b) Applying the product rule to the expression in part (a), we get

$\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{r^2}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}(2r\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+2s\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}})=2\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+2r\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})+2s\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}})$

So I made upto this point. Now the author uses the chain rule once more and I am completely nowhere.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{x^2}}(2r)+\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}}(2s)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}})=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}})\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}})\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}(2r)+\frac{\partial^2{z}}{\partial{y^2}}(2s)$

How did he use the chain rule here? In the equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{r}}$, he puts $(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})$ in the middle of $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}})\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}$ becomes $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}$ surrounding it. It seems all out of the blue.
I'm completely lost. I'm so depressed.

Comment: $z$ is a function of $x,y$ . So $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $ is also a function of $x,y$ . Hence ,while taking $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ of that , we have to keep in mind to first change to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and then multplying by $\frac{\partial  x}{\partial r} $ by the chain rule.

Comment: what do $\frac{\partial d}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial d}{dy}$ mean? maybe that is what makes me confused

Comment: They mean nothing but finding the derivative with respect to  an independent variable while treating the other independent vaiable constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing for the part where you are having the difficulty .

It is clear to you if $z(x,y)$ is a function of $x,y$ (where $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $s$ and $r$) then

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}  \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}  \quad (1)$

Now to find $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}  $,  let $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=u(x,y)$   and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=v(x,y)$

So
$\frac{\partial }{\partial r} \big( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\big)= \frac{\partial }{\partial r}(u(x,y))$

Thus from $(1)$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}  \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} $

$=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}(2r)+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y\partial x }  (2s)$

Now similarly find $\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\big(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\big)$ using $v(x,y)$ and the equality $(1)$ with which you are comfortable.

Substitute in the expression for $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}$ and you will get the required answer.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer has helped, you have the option of accepting my answer by clicking at the tick mark.